# How to access live server without port in VS Code extension?

Tags: html, web, url, visual-studio-code, port

I used [VS Code Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) Extension and customized Host to `play.dev` like bellow:
[image]

but when I want to access it, I should enter port number:

[image]
[image]

How can I access `play.dev` URL without port number?